# Adding variables to $_SESSION

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have got a basic login script at the moment.

When the user logs in 2 variables are defined:

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['user_id'];
$_SESSION['username'] = $user['username'];
```

the index.php file has this

```
session_start();
if(array_key_exists('user_id', $_SESSION) && array_key_exists('username', $_SESSION)):
```

That is all fine, however once the session is started I would like to add more values from a database so I have this code here:

```
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$_SESSION = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
```

When I do this it overrides the $_SESSION['user_id'] and $_SESSION['username'].
I tried this:

```
$_SESSION .= mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
```

but it didn't work.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks
peter

Comment: I would like to add that this is a bad idea. You should only store the user ID in the session as the username, role, email, etc.. might change at some point. It's better to load what is needed on each page.

Comment: If I do that then the site will be slower as it is loading loads of data each time.  The data on this database won't change unless the user changes it,  when the user changes his account info the $_SESSION variables will be re-defined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you're setting the value of the variable `$_SESSION` to the return value of  `mysql_fetch_assoc($res);`.

What you want to do is something like `$_SESSION['query_result'] = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)`. If you just want to add a single column of your database result to the session you would do it like this:

```
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$_SESSION['myKey'] = $data['myKey'];
```

Answer (score 6):

$_SESSION is an array. You are over-riding the entire `$_SESSION` variable. Do this instead:

```
$_SESSION['data'] = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Answer (score 1):

Try merging the arrays

```
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$_SESSION = array_merge(mysql_fetch_assoc($res), $_SESSION);
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: Switch the order of array merge's parameters to avoid overwriting previous values in $_SESSION.

Answer (score 1):

Functions mysql_* are deprecated and removed in the future, use PDO or MySQLi is recommended.

Some hosters have disabled these functions.

Comment: This was asked 2 years ago :)